# Why is the isTrackingAvailable() method not implemented in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping?

Tags: magento-1.9

The class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` implements the interface `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface` which has two functions defined: `getAllowedMethods()` and `isTrackingAvailable()`. But only `getAllowedMethods()` is implemented and `isTrackingAvailable()` is not.

Why doesn't this cause an error?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, I'd really appreciate it if you would take the time to click the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! It's a bit tricky: Magento shipping models extend the class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`, which has a `isTrackingAvailable()` method, and implement the interface `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`, which specifies a `getAllowedMethods()` function and a `isTrackingAvailable()` function.

The abstract class provides a concrete implementation of the `isTrackingAvailable()` method that can be overridden in child classes, but the `getAllowedMethods()` function must be implemented by the child class.

So, it works because it is implemented in the parent class that the shipping method model extends.